# Launch Screen AND Launch Images to Support iOS 7 And 8

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode6

I am using Xcode 6 and Swift in my iPhone Application. The 'Deployment Target' is 7.1 as needs to support for iPhone 4 and above.

I have selected 'iPhone' as devices under 'Deployment Info' (This is an iPhone App, not iPad)

Even though this is an iPhone app, I know iPads also can install it as an iPhone app and use in there (OS provides the option by zooming the app in iPad)...

Therefore I am testing with the simulator to see how it's going to look like on iPads too. All good but the launch image is **not** loading in **iOS 7.1 iPad** simulators, instead it shows the default black screen. But it works in iPad 8.0 simulators.

I have defined a '**Launch Screen**' to work with iOS 8 and works perfect with iOS 8 iPad/iPhone simulators

iOS 7 does NOT support for 'Launch Screen' and required to have 'Launch images' instead... Therefore following screenshot shows the launch images I have defined for different scenarios of iOS 7 devices (Different colors for test purposes). These launch images works great in all **iPhone 7.1** simulator but not with any **iPad 7.1** simulators.

[image]

I am not quite sure if it's a bug in iPad 7.1 simulator or if that's the real behaviour and I am missing something in there. I need to display a same sort of a Launch Image in iOS 7.1 iPad simulators as well. At the moment (iPhone 7.1/ iPhone 8.0 / iPad 8.0) working fine.

```
1). iPhone 8.0 Simulators - Display 'Launch Screen' and works fine
2). iPad 8.0 Simulators   - Display 'Launch Screen' and works fine
3). iPhone 7.1 Simulators - Picks correct 'Launch Image' and works fine
4). iPad 7.1 Simulators   - DOES NOT pick the correct 'Launch Image' and instead load nothing (The default blank black screen)
```

**Edits**

Screenshot of the settings is as follows

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to clean up your project after adding the launch images and before building it?

Comment: Hi Razvan,  Yes I cleaned, rebult But the same result.... It's only in iPad 7.1 Simulators... All sized iphone simulators (7.1) picks the correct one... iOS 8 iphones/Ipads simulators works fine as well (They display Launch screen Not these images as I expect)

Comment: Hi there. Did you select in your project's settings 'Use Assets Catalog' for the 'Launch Images Source' option?

Comment: Hi, Yes, I have selected it in there. That's why iPhone 7.1 Simulators picks it. Wonder why just iPad 7.1 simulators not getting it

Comment: I will add a screen-shot of the settings as "edits" to my question

Comment: Oh.. I've re-read your post and I see that your app isn't an universal app. You don't see any iPad-specific launch image on iOS 7 because the app is actually running its iPhone version on the iPad while the `Launch Screen` feature is iOS 8 and above only. `Launch Images` from assets catalog are working with iOS 7 and 8 while the `Launch Screen` is available since iOS 8.

Comment: Yes Razvan, That's why I am using launch images (As it's a requirement of iOS 7).. I wonder why it's not getting the iphone related launch image in this case then... Just displaying black default screen instead...

Comment: Indeed, that's curious...